# How to build a StaggeredGridLayout in Compose that works with the paging library?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am trying to mimic the Pinterest UI[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compose now supports lazy staggered grid layouts.
[LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/staggeredgrid/package-summary#LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.staggeredgrid.StaggeredGridCells,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.staggeredgrid.LazyStaggeredGridState,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Horizontal,androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.FlingBehavior,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1)) is the answer!

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to reuse the code written for supporting pagination with LazyColumn and LazyGrid with some modification it works for me

```
 @OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
 fun <T : Any> LazyStaggeredGridScope.items(
    items: LazyPagingItems<T>,
    key: ((item: T) -> Any)? = null,
    itemContent: @Composable LazyStaggeredGridItemScope.(item: T) -> Unit
) {
    items(
        count = items.itemCount,
        key = if (key == null) null else { index ->
            val item = items.peek(index)
            if (item == null) {
                PagingPlaceholderKey(index)
            } else {
                key(item)
            }
        }
    ) { index ->
       items[index]?.let {
           itemContent(it)
       }
    }
}


@SuppressLint("BanParcelableUsage")
private data class PagingPlaceholderKey(private val index: Int) : Parcelable {
    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeInt(index)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object {
        @Suppress("unused")
        @JvmField
        val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<PagingPlaceholderKey> =
            object : Parcelable.Creator<PagingPlaceholderKey> {
                override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel) =
                    PagingPlaceholderKey(parcel.readInt())

                override fun newArray(size: Int) = arrayOfNulls<PagingPlaceholderKey?>(size)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to a multiplatform solution, consider using `fun getDefaultLazyLayoutKey(index: Int): Any` in `androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout`.